# result of the application of nnet R

Tags: r

I am using nnet model to classify data and I have got this result

```
X= varfix[,2:18]
H=class.ind(varfix$y)

model=nnet(X,H,size=2,decay=0) 
# weights:  40
initial  value 23949.796377 
final  value 23137.000000 
converged
predX=predict(model,X) 
predX=apply(predX,1,which.is.max) 
classX=apply(H,1,which.is.max) 
table(classX,predX)
      predX
classX     2
     1 23137
     2 23137
```

hello,thanks for editing the code :) then what I want is to know if the code I used is correct or not ?
I did not understand the table command's result , did it means that valuesin class 2 are well classed and in class 1 are badly classed does it mean that  the error rate is about 0.5?
in other words

```
               predX
classX        2
     1          23137
     2          23137
```

is it equivalent to 
           predX

```
classX    1    2

     1    0      23137

     2    0     23137
```

?
thanks aicho
when I typed fix(X) the data was correct but for H I got the following

```
          0       1
     1    1      0

     2    1      0

     3    1      0

         .       .

         .       .

         .       .

   23138 0       1

   23139 0       1

    .     .       .

    .     .       .
```

thanks a lot for any help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Comment: Your interpretation of the `table` command is correct. The issue is why you have no performance when you train and test on the same data. For that, we need to look at the data `X` and `H`.